# Javascript dependency list

Tags: javascript

I have a list of elements where I need to figure out the dependency.

I have:

```
[{
  "a": ["b", "d"]
}, {
  "d": ["c", "e"]
}]
```

`a` is depending on `b` and `d`, and `d` on `c` and `e`. Is there a way to construct the dependencies in a clever way for this? The output should (could) be:

```
["b", "c", "e", "d", "a"]
```

/Kristian

Comment: What is logic behind? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Define 'clever'. Is iterating through the objects not good enough?

Comment: Not sure what the array posted means. Do you want the dependencies for an element (in any order) + the element itself?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly what you want, but in my logic, c and e should be placed before d on the array. For example, if you want to load libraries.

Comment: Clever is for a solution other than straight iteration but if it is the best way it's clever :). I'm looking for a generic way of creating the list.

Comment: @Gael, you're right. I've updated the list. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Asken how do you want to handle circular dependency (`a` requires `b`, `b` requires `a`)?

Comment: Why are the dependencies in separate one-key objects? Shouldn't that be a single object with multiple keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you wanted the list of recursive dependencies of an element, including the element itself, in any order:

"for every dependency, add its dependencies to the dependency list" is clever enough?

```
function recursiveDependencies (dependencies, element){
  var output = [element];
  for(i=0; i<output.length(); i++){
    dependencies[output[i]].forEach(function(x){
      if(output.indexOf(x)<0){ //prevent duplicates
        output.push(x)
      }
    })
  }
  return output;
}
```

If you want the element itself at the end rather than the beginning, you can fix that with `output.push(output.shift())`

---

If you want your dependencies in such an order that every element precedes the elements that depend on it, then you'll have to define how to handle circular dependencies. One way to handle that is detect a circular dependency and fail.

If every dependency is needed by at most one element, then you can use the previous algorithm: simply read the output backwards (or reverse the array or use `unshift` instead of `push` (warning: performance drop))

---

The dependencies form a graph, and you are looking for its topological sort. One (inefficent) way would be to order the nodes in depth-first order and reinsert them if they are reentered. You could use the Open stack to detect errors - if a child is reentered from its parent, then you have a circular dependency.

A better solution would be to use the standard topological sort algorithm: While there are unsorted nodes, pick one that has no unresolved dependencies:

```
function recursiveDependencies (dependencies, root){
  var nodes={};
  var nodeCount=0;
  var ready=[];
  var output=[];

  // build the graph
  function add(element){
     nodeCount++;
     nodes[element]={needs:[], neededBy:[], name: element};
     if(dependencies[element]){
       dependencies[element].forEach(function(dependency){
         if(!nodes[dependency]) add(dependency);
         nodes[element].needs.push(nodes[dependency]);
         nodes[dependency].neededBy.push(nodes[element]);
       });
     }
     if(!nodes[element].needs.length) ready.push(nodes[element]);
  }

  if(root){
    add(root)
  } else {
     for (element in dependencies){
       if(!nodes[element]) add(element);
    }
  }


  //sort the graph
  while(ready.length){
    var dependency = ready.pop();
    output.push(dependency.name);
    dependency.neededBy.forEach(function(element){
      element.needs = element.needs.filter(function(x){return x!=dependency})
      if(!element.needs.length) ready.push(element)
    })
  }

  //error-check
  if(output.length != nodeCount){
    throw "circular dependency detected"
  }

  return output;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xq5dz/4/

Comment: Yeah, no. That's not really what I want. I want a list in order of dependency for a non-ordered list where the dependents are defined.

Comment: That is, every dependent is before the depending element? Your (original) example is not in that order, and it's not possible if a circular dependency exists.

Comment: @Asken how do you want to handle circular dependency (`a` requires `b`, `b` requires `a`)?

Comment: At this point I'm not worried about that but if you know how to deal with it please include it... it shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Asken this will produce the requested order if no two elements share a dependency

Comment: I don't see how I would use it with the list I provided in the example though... I must be tired. Can you provide a full example?

Comment: @Asken updated with a general solution. It's not too short but it uses recursion so you might consider it "clever" ;-)

Comment: It's clever enough and was what I wanted except that I don't really have a root. I can just as well start with "d" instead of "a" in which case it won't return the entire thing.