# How to sort an array with sometimes incomparable values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

I am trying to sort values that are sometimes incomparable with each other. The data that I am sorting resembles a tree where

```
1. if a depends on b, then a should be sorted after b
2. if b depends on a, then b should be sorted after a
3. if neither a or b depend on each other then they are incomparable and no comparison can be drawn
```

I am currently using the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function in javascript with a custom compare function. But I suspect that it is not appropriate as I require essentially [Topological Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting)

Example Code with tests:

```
// k depends on nothing - but every other element depends on k, so k should come first
var k = {
  uuid: 'k',
  dependsOn: []
};

// z depends on k and so k must come before z
var z = {
  uuid: 'z',
  dependsOn: ['k']
}

// y should be go before x as x depends on y
// y also depends on k so k should go before y
var y = {
  uuid: 'y',
  dependsOn: ['k']
}

// x has both y and k as its dependencies
var x = {
  uuid: 'x',
  dependsOn: ['y', 'k']
}

function compare(a, b) {
  // if they have the same uuid; then they are the same
  if (a.uuid === b.uuid) {
    return 0
  }

  // if a depends on b, then a should be after b
  for (var i = 0, len = a.dependsOn.length; i < len; i++) {
    var dependsOn = a.dependsOn[i];

    if (dependsOn === b.uuid) {
      return 1
    }
  }

  // if b depends on a, then b should be after a
  for (var i = 0, len = b.dependsOn.length; i < len; i++) {
    var dependsOn = b.dependsOn[i];

    if (dependsOn === a.uuid) {
      return -1
    }
  }

  // this is the edge case, 
  // if neither a or b depends on each other, then they don't have relative ranking
  return null
}

// this is every possible permutation - they should all sort to the same orders
// expected order k, z, y, x or k, y, z, x or k, y, x, z
// because:
// k -> z  as z depends on k
// k -> y  as y depends on k
// no relative ranking between z and y as they don't depend on each other
// x depends on both y and k so x will come after them
var perms = [
  [x, y, z, k],
  [x, y, k, z],
  [x, z, y, k],
  [x, z, k, y],
  [x, k, y, z],
  [x, k, z, y],
  [y, x, z, k],
  [y, x, k, z],
  [y, z, x, k],
  [y, z, k, x],
  [y, k, x, z],
  [y, k, z, x],
  [z, x, y, k],
  [z, x, k, y],
  [z, y, x, k],
  [z, y, k, x],
  [z, k, x, y],
  [z, k, y, x],
  [k, x, y, z],
  [k, x, z, y],
  [k, y, x, z],
  [k, y, z, x],
  [k, z, x, y],
  [k, z, y, x],
]

var _ = require('underscore')
perms.forEach(function(perm) {
  var s = perm.sort(compare)
  var p = _.pluck(s, 'uuid')
  console.log(p, _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'z', 'y', 'x']) || _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'y', 'z', 'x']) || _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'y', 'x', 'z']))
})
```

Example Output (with annotation):

```
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'x', 'z', 'y' ] false \\ x depends on k and y so it should be after y
[ 'k', 'x', 'z', 'y' ] false
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'x', 'z', 'y' ] false \\ x depends on k and y so it should be after y
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'z', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'z', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'z', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'x', 'z', 'y' ] false \\ x depends on k and y so it should be after y
[ 'k', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] true
[ 'k', 'y', 'z', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
[ 'k', 'z', 'y', 'x' ] true
```

Comment: A [compare function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) can be used with *sort* that returns -ve, +ve or 0 values to create the required order. The "incomparable" case is 0, or essentially a == b.

Comment: I did provide a compare function. And if I return 0 on the incomparable case, the sort function thinks that they are the equal (which is different from incomparable) and will return the incorrect results

Comment: Yes, you want a topological sort. Since you know that term now, you should be able to find a js implementation on the web ([here is one on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13303185/1048572)). Or just implement the algorithms lined out in the WP article. If you need further help, please let us know; if you code a solution [you might answer your own question with it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thanks Bergi, when I asked the question I didn't know about topological sort yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a seemingly not very actively maintained library that did the job:

[toposort](https://github.com/marcelklehr/toposort)

```
// k depends on nothing - but every other element depends on k, so k should come first
var k = {
  uuid: 'k',
  dependsOn: []
};

// z depends on k and so k must come before z
var z = {
  uuid: 'z',
  dependsOn: ['k']
}

// y should be go before x as x depends on y
// y also depends on k so k should go before y
var y = {
  uuid: 'y',
  dependsOn: ['k']
}

// x has both y and k as its dependencies
var x = {
  uuid: 'x',
  dependsOn: ['y', 'k']
};

function Edges(array) {
  var edges = []
  for (var k in array) {
    var node = array[k]

    node.dependsOn.forEach(function(dependency) {
      edges.push([dependency].concat(node.uuid))
    })
  }

  return edges
}

// this is every possible permutation - they should all sort to the same orders
// expected order k, z, y, x or k, y, z, x or k, y, x, z
// because:
// k -> z  as z depends on k
// k -> y  as y depends on k
// no relative ranking between z and y as they don't depend on each other
// x depends on both y and k so x will come after them
var perms = [
  [x, y, z, k],
  [x, y, k, z],
  [x, z, y, k],
  [x, z, k, y],
  [x, k, y, z],
  [x, k, z, y],
  [y, x, z, k],
  [y, x, k, z],
  [y, z, x, k],
  [y, z, k, x],
  [y, k, x, z],
  [y, k, z, x],
  [z, x, y, k],
  [z, x, k, y],
  [z, y, x, k],
  [z, y, k, x],
  [z, k, x, y],
  [z, k, y, x],
  [k, x, y, z],
  [k, x, z, y],
  [k, y, x, z],
  [k, y, z, x],
  [k, z, x, y],
  [k, z, y, x],
]

var _ = require('underscore')
var toposort = require('toposort')
perms.forEach(function(perm) {
  var p = toposort(Edges(perm));
  console.log(p, _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'z', 'y', 'x']) || _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'y', 'z', 'x']) || _.isEqual(p, ['k', 'y', 'x', 'z']))
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need the behavior of topological sort, my graph js library at github does have this type of implementation:

https://github.com/chen0040/js-graph-algorithms

The sample code from the graph algorithms library that does the top sort is as follows:

`var jsgraphs = require('js-graph-algorithms');`

```
var dag = new jsgraphs.DiGraph(7); 

dag.addEdge(0, 5); // edge point from vertex 0 to 5
dag.addEdge(0, 2);
dag.addEdge(0, 1);
dag.addEdge(3, 6);
dag.addEdge(3, 5);
dag.addEdge(3, 4);
dag.addEdge(5, 4);
dag.addEdge(6, 4);
dag.addEdge(6, 0);
dag.addEdge(3, 2);
dag.addEdge(1, 4);

var ts = new jsgraphs.TopologicalSort(dag);

var order = ts.order();
console.log(order); // display array which is the topological sort order
```